# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have table:

**HTML**

```
<table id="mydata">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data 1</th>
            <th>Data 2</th>
            <th>Data 3</th>
            <th>Data 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="main">
            <td class="data_1">A</td>
            <td class="data_2">B</td>
            <td class="data_3">C</td>
            <td class="data_4">D</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

When i'm using dataTable to sort with jquery:

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery('#mydata').dataTable({
    "sDom": " ",
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    'bFilter':false,                        
    "aoColumns": [
        null,               
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
});
```

It's worked.

But, when i add child rows for **main**:

**HTML**

```
<table id="mydata">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data 1</th>
            <th>Data 2</th>
            <th>Data 3</th>
            <th>Data 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="main">
            <td class="data_1">A</td>
            <td class="data_2">B</td>
            <td class="data_3">C</td>
            <td class="data_4">D</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="detail-header">
            <td><strong>A1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>B1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>C1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>D1</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="detail">
            <td><strong>A2</strong></td>
            <td><strong>B2</strong></td>
            <td><strong>C2</strong></td>
            <td><strong>D2</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="control">
            <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Show details</a></td>
            <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Hide details</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In that html: **detail-header**, **detail** and **control** are childs of **main** and they show when click to **Show details**, it's should ignore when sort but i seem they also sort by dataTable so i received error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
```

Comment: detail-header, detail and control are not childs of main, they are sibblings of main. Did you expect tbody to be main?

Comment: yeah, i'm confused. I want datatable just sort with main, and detail-header, detail and control will depend on results is sorted.

Comment: oh now i get it. You need to check the data table plugin if it allows to sort any particular row!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dataTables does [**not accept colspans in `<tbody>`**](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/16225/colspan-or-rowspan-to-tbody). Place the last row (the row with links) in a `<tfoot>` instead :

```
<tfoot>
    <tr class="control">
        <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Show details</a></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Hide details</a></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/71zcn578/**